# mix firebase promises with ES6 promises

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

as far as I can tell, for some reason FB is using it's own promises implementation and not the ES6 standard.

Is it possible/safe to mix FB and ES6 promises ? for example in a 'then' chain ?

```
let p1=firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
let p2=new Promise( ...

p1.then(ps).then( // ?? is this ok ?
```

thx!

Comment: Should work. Are you having problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> firebase.Promise is the same as the native Promise implementation when available in the current environment, otherwise it is a compatible implementation of the Promise/A+ spec.

Extracted from its docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.Promise

Check if in your environment you're changing the Promise implementation to Bluebird or something like that.

The FireBase promises and ES6 standard promises should work together without any problem.

Hope this helps.